# Rails Param Not Found for Destroy Link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting the error: "ActionController::ParameterMissing in SitesController#destroy"

And it says: "param not found: site"

Show view:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', @site, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Controller Destroy Action

```
  def destroy
    @site = Site.find(site_params)
    if @site.present?
        @site.destroy
    end
    redirect_to "sites#index"
  end

  private
    def site_params
        params.require(:site).permit(:user_id, :domain)
    end
```

Routes

```
           sites GET    /sites(.:format)               sites#index
                 POST   /sites(.:format)               sites#create
        new_site GET    /sites/new(.:format)           sites#new
       edit_site GET    /sites/:id/edit(.:format)      sites#edit
            site GET    /sites/:id(.:format)           sites#show
                 PATCH  /sites/:id(.:format)           sites#update
                 PUT    /sites/:id(.:format)           sites#update
                 DELETE /sites/:id(.:format)           sites#destroy
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but did you rake first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the rake task, the route for destroy is defined as

```
DELETE /sites/:id(.:format)           sites#destroy
```

and since the link is not expected to post any data, the only param value you can access is the site id

```
params[:id]
```

You need to change your method to

```
@site = Site.find(params[:id])
```

instead of

```
@site = Site.find(site_params)
```

Moreover, there are a few additional changes you can apply

```
if @site.present?
    @site.destroy
end
```

This check is meaningless. If find returns a result, it means the record is there.

```
redirect_to "sites#index"
```

This is an horrible redirect command (assuming it works). Use the named route instead.

Putting all the changes together the final result is

```
def destroy
  @site = Site.find(params[:id])
  @site.destroy
  redirect_to sites_url
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using strong parameters properly in this case.  The params passed in this instance are simply an `id`.  As a result, your code should simply be:

```
def destroy
  @site = Site.find(params[:id])

  if @site.present?
    @site.destroy
  end

  redirect_to "sites#index"
end
```